# jQuery UI autocomplete is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

This is my JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input#suggestZams").autocomplete({
        source: "content/prevadzky/zam/zam_json2.php?letter=all",
        minLength: 1,
        delay: 0,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            alert(1);
        }
    });
});
//]]>
</script>
```

This is my HTML:

```
<input id="suggestZams" class="input" size="10" />
```

The URL `zam_json2.php?letter=all` returns this json:

```
[
{ "id": "31440", "value": "Andrej\u010d\u00e1k, Ing." },
{ "id": "31690", "value": "Alexovi\u010d , Ing." },
{ "id": "31796", "value": "Antoni\u010d , Ing." },
{ "id": "31989", "value": "Antolik , Ing." },
{ "id": "32010", "value": "Ambrozov\u00e1 RNDr., PhD." },
{ "id": "32014", "value": "Aksam\u00edt" },
{ "id": "32024", "value": "Angelovi\u010d" },
{ "id": "32102", "value": "Andrej\u010d\u00e1k" },
{ "id": "32168", "value": "Avukov\u00e1 , Ing." },
{ "id": "32177", "value": "Andr\u00e1\u0161" },
{ "id": "32181", "value": "Andrej\u010d\u00e1kov\u00e1 , Mgr." },
{ "id": "32403", "value": "Arend\u00e1\u0161 , Bc." },
{ "id": "47379", "value": "An\u010fal" },
{ "id": "47399", "value": "Adam\u00edk , Ing." },
{ "id": "50022", "value": "Abo\u0161i" },
{ "id": "50085", "value": "Armer\u00eda Olmedo , Ing." },
{ "id": "53468", "value": "Anto\u0161" },
{ "id": "54837", "value": "Adamec , Ing." },
{ "id": "56659", "value": "Apostolou" },
{ "id": "57820", "value": "Alez\u00e1r" },
{ "id": "58576", "value": "Andrej\u010d\u00e1k , Bc." },
{ "id": "58587", "value": "Aronov\u00e1 , Ing." },
{ "id": "58595", "value": "Abaffy , Bc." },
{ "id": "58607", "value": "Adamec , Bc." },
{ "id": "58643", "value": "Antu\u0161 , Ing." },
{ "id": "62277", "value": "Adam\u010d\u00e1k , Mgr." },
{ "id": "62379", "value": "Andruch" },
{ "id": "63415", "value": "Adamkovi\u010d , Ing." }
]
```

Comment: Check with firebug what the actual URL is that JQuery is trying to access, might be content/prevadzky/zam/zam_json2.php?letter=all?t=...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quote:

> Autocomplete can be customized to work
>   with various data sources, by just
>   specifying the source option. A data
>   source can be:
>
> - an Array with local data
> - a String, specifying a URL
> - a Callback
>
> When a String is used, the
>   Autocomplete plugin expects that
>   string to point to a URL resource that
>   will return JSON data. It can be on
>   the same host or on a different one
>   (must provide JSONP). The request
>   parameter "term" gets added to that
>   URL. The data itself can be in the
>   same format as the local data
>   described above.

What you are doing looks odd to me. I think that you will actually need to edit the server side script so that it expects the query string variable `term` instead of letter **and** returns an array of strings or an array of `{label, value}` objects instead of {value, id}.

If the URL `content/prevadzky/zam/zam_json2.php?letter=all` is provides the "complete" list of words at once, you can do something along these lines:

```
$.getJSON("content/prevadzky/zam/zam_json2.php?letter=all", function(data) {
    var datacopy = $.map(data, function(item) {
        return {
            label: item.value,
            value: item.id
        };
    });
    $("input#suggestZams").autocomplete({
        source: datacopy,
        minLength: 1,
        delay: 0,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            alert(typeof ui);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It works btu only after I have reverted my jquery version to 1.4.2. It doesn't work with jquery 1.5.1.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the data from a url you have to define a function for source:

```
source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({url: "content/prevadzky/zam/zam_json2.php?letter=all",
            dataType: "json",
            ...
           });
    },
...
```

**EDIT:**

In the docs it says: `source` can be a URL. In this case, try to change the JSON response to have `'label'` instead of `'id'` in the returned objects.

Answer (score 1):

Here an Script that work for me in jQuery 1.5.1.

```
source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "...",
        dataType: "json",
        ...
        success: function( data ) {
            # data = json response
        }
    });
}
```